# Running a mysql stored procedure using php

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

[image: Capture of the mysql stored procedure]Hello, I am trying to run a mysql stored procedure called 'sp_tbl_prototype_edit'

This stored procedure has two parameters :

- p_Techname (VARCHAR(10))
- p_Value (INT)

It looks the PHP function below does not save (edit the value in the database) the value as I would like.

```
function edit_record($title, $value){

    // Prepares IN parameters
    $mysqli->query("SET p_Techname = '" . $title . "'");
    $mysqli->query("SET p_Value = '" . $value ."'");

    // Call stored procedure
    if(!$mysqli->query("CALL sp_tbl_prototype_edit (@p_Techname, @p_Value)"))
    {
    if($mysqli) $mysqli->close(); // Close DB connection
    //header('Location: error.php?error=QueryFailure');
    die();
    }

    if($mysqli) $mysqli->close(); // Close DB connection
}
```

Do you have any suggestion to troubleshoot this, please? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: if the query fails, you simply redirect. you should have the system TELL you why it failed, e.g. `die($mysqli->error);`. And note that you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Why aren't you passing the parameters directly `$mysqli->query("CALL sp_tbl_prototype_edit ($title, $value)")` ? I don't think your temporary variables will persist between queries. If that works, then you should parameterize them - *especially* if `$input` and `$value` are user-submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Set the session variable correctly with `@` as prefix:

   ```
   $mysqli->query("SET @p_Techname = '" . $title . "'");
   $mysqli->query("SET @p_Value = '" . $value ."'");
   ```
2. Call the stored procedure using the values instead of variables:

   ```
   $mysqli->query("CALL sp_tbl_prototype_edit ('" . $title . "', '" . $value ."')")
   ```